# Git Push to Azure Master states "Everything up to date" when it's not

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, push

Hi i've been trying to push to Azure through Git but it keeps stating everything up to date when it's not.

[image: Git Screenshot]

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
I was following this Azure page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-php

And i'm trying to push exactly like it says on the documentation so i'm really confused why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `git status` first: you need to make sure you did commit on the master branch and not:

- on another branch
- or on no branch at all (detached HEAD)

From [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-php), you should have completed one git push already, after `az webapp create`

The output of git remote -v will help too, determining the name of the remote to use (since in your case, origin referes to GitHub)

```
git checkout master
git merge arduino-firebase
git push -u xxx master
```

After the -u option, a simple git push will be enough since the local master branch will be associated with the Azure remote one.
Check the output of `git branch -avv` for confirmation.

Comment: yep the first git push went through but when i tried updating it by adding and committing more files it just states "everything up to date"

Comment: @user3717206 hance the need to know the output of git status.

Comment: Thats what it shows when i use Git Status On branch arduino-firebase
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/arduino-firebase' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean

Comment: @user3717206 the a `git push -u origin arduino-firebase` will do.

Comment: it says: fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in /arduino-firebase

Comment: @user3717206 I have edited the comment: remove the /

Comment: Okay it worked but it just pushed to the github branch and not to the Azure Master Branch

Comment: @user3717206 then: `git checkout master; git merge arduino-firebase; git push -u origin master`

Comment: If i do that it's just gonna merge my arduino-firebase branch with my git-hub master branch and not push to the Azure Master branch which is what i'm trying to do

Comment: @user3717206 GitHub? Check the output of  `git remote -v`: do you have one referring to Azure?

Comment: yep i checked git remote -v and i have a (fetch) and (push) referring to Azure and another (fetch) and (push) referring to the origin github

Comment: @user3717206 Then use git push -u xxx master, with xxx being the name of the remote referring to Azure, assumin gthat you have the right to push to that Azure remote repo.

Comment: Okay that worked thank you very much it pushed successfully to the azure master branch